# Error while trying to make struct function

Tags: c

[varibels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htnwa.png)

I have a function that gets an array and suppose to return a struct

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct
  char name[16];
  int    year;
  int month;
  int day;
c }
```

and a function.

The function basically gets an array and divides the array to the struct. When I get to the end of the function, I'm getting a runtime error:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'temp_date' was corrupted.

Here is the function:

```
city cityspliter(char *info)
    city temp;
    int t,i, length;
    char temp_date[2];

    length = strlen(info);

    for (i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (info[i] != '~')
            temp.name[i - 1] = info[i];
        else
        {
            temp.name[i - 1] = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }

    t = 0;
    while (info[i+1]!='/')
    {
        temp_date[t] = info[i + 1];
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    temp.day = get_number(temp_date);

    t = 0;
    while (info[i + 1] != '/')
    {
        temp_date[t] = info[i + 1];
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    temp.month = get_number(temp_date);

    while (info[i + 2] != '>')
    {
        temp_date[t] = info[i + 2];
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    temp.month = get_number(temp_date);

    t = 0;
    while (info[i] != '>')
    {
        temp_date[t] = info[i];
        i++;
        t++;
    }
    temp.year = get_number(temp_date);

    return temp;
}
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: The value of string `info` is a secret you have not posted.  Better to state your inputs, and expected results.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: most likely at some point `t` is greater than 1.

Comment: i edited the question with the variables when i get the error. the temp_city is the result i want, it's look fine

Comment: t need to be greater than 1, and it looks like I get the runtime error in the end of the function - after the return.

Comment: `temp` is a local variable on the stack in the function `citysplitter`. It goes out of scope as soon as the function ends.

Comment: ok, thank u for the t notice. it was spuse to be greater than 1 but it's was 3 one time, it's solve every thing.

Comment: That's true, @FredK, but irrelevant.  A *copy* of the structure is returned to the caller.  This is not the problem it would be if the OP were returning a *pointer* to a local variable.